# whitelist web apps on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

**My assumed architecture, hopefully I am not violating current best practices.**

1. a single service/module/app that defines entry point for all datastore access, hosted as a subdomain on one domain.

   - probably only has API, no html
   - probably on App Engine, Python
   - users will need to authenticate for some data, but not all.
2. on multiple other domains or subdomains, statically hosted and served javascript front-ends (SPAs) will make https calls to the datastore service on first domain.

   - back-end should manage data separately (multi-tenant) for each client coming from a different domain.
   - clients are probably [hosted statically](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) on various Cloud Storage instances

**Some questions:**

1. Is this the problem that [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications#challenge) solves today (2016) or is that outdated technology? (I say outdated because the javascript library does not offer Promise interface).
2. How should the datstore service **whitelist** the clients coming from different domains or mobile apps?

Comment: 1. the js client for endpoints uses promises 2. that sounds like a scenario where you would use authentication, since you don't know the IPs 3. Since you're asking about software and hosting architecture your question could be considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow.

Comment: It sounds like I misinterpreted "Additionally, the Cloud Endpoints client library does not support the Promise API of AngularJS for describing this kind of asynchronous processing."

Comment: that's correct. Angular uses its own $q service for promises. When you create an angular service for your endpoints you can easily wrap your cloud endpoints calls with `$q.defer()`s.